# Rewrite an interval union algorithm functionally

Tags: python, algorithm, functional-programming

Suppose we've got an array of intervals `[(a1, b1), (a2, b2), ... , (an, bn)]` sorted with respect to starting positions and length. We want to unite all intersecting intervals. Here is a small sample data set that contains at least 2 isolated groups of intervals:

```
from random import randint

def gen_interval(min, max):
    return sorted((randint(min, max), randint(min, max)))


sample = sorted([gen_interval(0, 100) for _ in xrange(5)] + 
                [gen_interval(101, 200) for _ in xrange(5)],
                key=lambda (a, b): (a, b - a))
```

And a couple of functions we need to check for intersection and to extend intervals.

```
def intersects(interval1, interval2):
    a1, b1 = interval1
    a2, b2 = interval2
    return (a1 <= a2 <= b1) or (a1 <= b2 <= b1)


def extend(interval1, interval2):
    a1, b1 = interval1
    a2, b2 = interval2
    return (a1, b2) if b2 > b1 else (a1, b1)
```

We can simply accomplish the task using standard imperative programming:

```
result = []
for interval in sample:
    if result and intersects(result[-1], interval):
        result[-1] = extend(result[-1], interval)
    else:
        result.append(interval)
```

But I want to rewrite this using functional programming. My closest shot is:

```
subsets = []
for interval in sample:
    if subsets and any(intersects(x, interval) for x in subsets[-1]):
        subsets[-1].append(interval)
    else:
        subsets.append([interval])

result = map(lambda x: reduce(extend, x), subsets)
```

Here half of the work is done functionally, but I still have to split the initial array using an imperative approach. How can I get the thing done using pure functional programming? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want; can you elaborate on what you mean by 'splitting the initial array using pure functional programming'?

Comment: The 1st approach is perfectly fine and readable while the 2nd one is artificially blown up and harder to understand. The goal is to write readable and understandable code, I don't really see where "pure functional programming" comes in.

Comment: @Cyphase There is no such line in my question. Nevertheless, what I mean is that my half-backed functional solution has to rely on imperative code to divide the initial sorted array into subarrays in which intervals form a continuum, while I want the algorithm to be purely functional.

Comment: Do you want to remove (replace) the `for` statement? If you are looking for something like `sample.each(<block-of-code>)` then take a look at **Ruby**.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Can you show what function is gen_interval?

Comment: @AnandSKumar got it. Sorry for the frustration.

Comment: As a side note, the `key` in your `sorted()` call is redundant (i.e. the resulting sort order doesn't change if you simply omit it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were getting close with the use of `reduce`. This solution accumulates the list of collapsed intervals with reduce.

```
def unite_intervals(intervals):
    def f(acc, element):
        if acc and intersects(acc[-1], element):
            return acc[:-1] + [extend(acc[-1], element)]
        else:
            return acc + [element]
    return reduce(f, intervals, [])
```

Also, this does a ton of reallocation since I'm using `+` on list objects to accumulate the result. For very large lists this will be inefficient. You may look into using something like the `pyrsistent` library for more efficient data structures to accumulate into.

Comment: Thank you. I'll study your solution as soon as I get back to my laptop. And I've added the `gen_interval` implementation. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @EliKorvigo - Thanks, I've tested it against your solution with gen_intervals and it looks like mine matches up.

Comment: Will replacing the `else: return acc + [element]` with `return acc.append(element) or acc` contradict functional purity? This will substantially increase performance.

Comment: So, it depends how pure you want to be. In this case it would not be an "observable" side-effect, so to callers of unite_intervals it will still as a pure function. So I would say it *results* in a pure function but it would not be a functional "formulation".

Comment: Also, you wouldn't want `return acc.append(element)` -- that would return None. You'd want to do `acc.append(element); return acc`. And make such a change for the if *and* else cases.

Comment: You missed the `or` part. In Python `return acc.append(element) or acc` returns `acc` after the append operation because the left-hand operand is `None` ~ `False`. That's a common trick. And since you can only `return` from a function once, the `else` statement is redundant.

Comment: Ah, indeed I literally didn't even notice the `or acc` at the end.

Comment: The code clearly will run slower than the imperative counterpart whatever we do, but performance is of no concern here. Thank you a lot for the code.